# Failed to compile. ./src/App.tsx SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <div>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, react-typescript

It seems that there is some issue with te closing tag, but I can not seem to find a solution anywhere.

I just started the project and the code is super simple:

App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header id="header" inverted as='h1'>Dishes Project</Header>
      </ DishesContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error "Failed to compile. ./src/App.tsx SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for " started showing up when I imported  the  </ DishesContainer>

import { DishesContainer } from './components/DishesContainer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were closing `DishesContainer` component incorrectly.

Try this instead:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header id="header" inverted as='h1'>Dishes Project</Header>
      <DishesContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here, with your DishesContainer component:

```
   function App() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <Header id="header" inverted as='h1'>Dishes Project</Header>
              <DishesContainer />
            </div>
          );
        }
        
   export default App;
```